SharePoint List Column Validation on Multiple Fields Not Working
I'm trying to enforce validation in an out of the box SharePoint list. When a value is selected in a choice column eg. Column A = 1, I want six other columns to become required. The column types are as follows:
Column B: Yes/No
Column C: Choice
Column D: Single line of text
Column E: Single line of text
Column F: Single line of text
Column G: Single line of text
Validation syntax: =IF([Column A]="1",AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Column B])),NOT(ISBLANK([Column C])),NOT(ISBLANK([Column D])),NOT(ISBLANK([Column E])),NOT(ISBLANK([Column F])),NOT(ISBLANK([Column G]))),TRUE)
Issue 1: It doesn't work on Yes/No type of column (Column B) i.e. I can submit the form by leaving it blank, but if I change it to Single line of text it works.
Issue 2: It allows me to submit the form If I select a value in Column C and leave everything else blank.
Issue 3: When I remove Column C from the syntax I can submit the form by leaving all required fields empty.
For issue 1: Tried changing column type to text, it worked but tried on another Yes/No type column, it didn't work. tried on a different list in a different site collection.
For issue 2 and 3:

Tried a different list in a different site collection.
Tried removing the choice type column and all validation stopped working.
Tried with just one or two columns, worked fine.


For the Yes/No column, there is no blank value for it. When you tick the checkbox in the Yes/No column, it shows Yes. When you do not tick the checkbox in the Yes/No column, it shows No.
If you want to the Yes/No column must be Yes and other columns not be blank, please use following formula.
=IF([Column A]="1",IF(AND([Column B]=TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK([Column C])),NOT(ISBLANK([Column D])),NOT(ISBLANK([Column E])),NOT(ISBLANK([Column F])),NOT(ISBLANK([Column G]))),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

I changed the Yes/No column to choice and the same thing happens. I was on call with Microsoft and created a brand new list with simple columns and was able to submit the form without filling out any required (validation) fields. The behavior is not consistent
